# Docking CFormView in SDI

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, sdi

I have a SDI app[MFC] with two spitter which divides the view into 3 views. Where i have implemented CFormview which has CListCtrl/CtreeCtrl in all 3 views.

What i want is to make the control fit to the screen in the application. The Ctrls doesn't fit to screen and doesn't scale when spitter is expaned or shriked. So how to i acheive the fit to screen functionality ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A CFormView has a static size and usually scrolls. So it isn't the real solution for you.
So don't use a CFormView.

You can divide each pane again with a splitter window to hold your tree ctrl and your list ctrl.
If you don't need Doc/View, create your own CWnd that contains a CListCtrl and a CTreeCtrl and overwrite WM_SIZE and resize the two child controls in it.

Using a CView as a parent will work too, again overwrite WM_SIZE so that the to child controls fir into the complete area of the view.

If you use CWnd or CView as a parent class, think about using IsDialogMessage to handle keyboard switching with VK_TAB between two windows...

Comment: A CFormView is resizable. The main barrier to doing that is that the dialog must have resizable borders. Also, I am nearly certain that "overwrite" here should be "override" and if you are German then that makes that nearly certain.

Answer (score 0):

When the splitter changes the size of any pane window that window receives WM_SIZE. Add a WM_SIZE handler to the CFormView(s) and in that function resize the child controls to fit. WM_SIZE passes you the new size and m_some_control.MoveWindow(...) can be used to resize each control.